# Is it possible to identify a role after building a Vuejs project?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, ecma

I have a file that exports some functions in a `Vuejs` project, and I need to use them also in an external environment .. in`Component` I know which function I should use by identifying by name and comparing with a .JSON file this works cool in the environment of `development` but when I build the project the functions are renamed as in the image:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Is there any other reference in these functions where I can identify them other than by name? any reference in memory I don't know? Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You can define a unique value in the body of each function and then when you have a reference to one of the functions in your list you can call the `toString()` method of the function reference to get the source code of the function - and then check whether the desired unique value is present in the code.

Something like this:

```
const myFunc1 = function (...)
{
  const uniqueIdent = 'zvjbesvfexrxe3cg4g3ewumkaj2hrz9m';
  .....
}
const myFunc2 = function (...)
{
  const uniqueIdent = 'y4wxfjedrr3mh6k5ju2gcff6wxafjcz5';
  .....
}

// make the list of functions globally available
window.myFuncList = { myFunc1, myFunc2 };

// try to find the uglyfied name of Func2
var key;
var realNameFunc2;
for (key in window.myFuncList)
{
  if (window.myFuncList[key].toString().indexOf('y4wxfjedrr3mh6k5ju2gcff6wxafjcz5') !== -1)
  {
    realNameFunc2 = key;
    break;
  }
}

// you can now invoke your function as realNameFunc2(...)
```